# Is storing JQuery variables possible?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering what storing a JQuery selection into a variable does. I tried the below example.

```
var images = $('div').find('img');
alert($(images[0]).attr('src'));
```

This works. However, if I use images[0] instead of $(images[0]), the code will not work. What I concluded is that the above code has created an array that contains DOM elements of the div img elements. Am I missing anything?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A jQuery object is an **array-like** object. You can access it *like* an array (it has numeric properties) and it has a `.length` property, but it is not an array (it does not inherit from `Array.prototype`).

When you access a jQuery object like that, i.e. `images[0]`, you will get back one of the selected DOM elements. After all, a jQuery object is just a collection of DOM elements.

In this case though, you could simply do

```
alert(images.attr('src'));
```

since `images` is a jQuery object.

Methods that don't return a jQuery object usually work with the first of the selected elements, and thus is equivalent to `$(images[0]).attr(...)` or `images.eq(0).attr(...)`.

Maybe you thought that [method chaining *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) (i.e. `a.b().c()`) is something "magical" but it's not. Each of the methods returns an object and instead of saving the return value in a variable, you immediately call another function on it.

---

Just to sum up: All selection methods return *jQuery objects*. Those objects are *array-like objects*. You can store them in variables as you like.

All of the following examples are equivalent:

```
// 1
$('div').find('img').attr('src');

// 2
var divs = $('div');
divs.find('img').attr('src');

// 3
var images = $('div').find('img');
images.attr('src');

// 4
var divs = $('div');
var images = divs.find('img');
images.attr('src');
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that a common naming convention might be to call the variable `$images` to indicate that it is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use jQuery to find objects, an array is always returned. If no elements are found, an empty array is returned. Each element in the array represents the raw DOM object in your HTML page.

You can call jQuery events only on an jQuery array and not on the element directly. The DOM element is of type HTML object and does not contain jQuery functions. To call a jQuery function like attr on a DOM element, you'll have to convert it to a jQuery object by calling $(object)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**First of all:** You don't need to do that. Do simply `images.attr("src")` instead, it's almostly the same as `$(images[0]).attr('src')` (and even faster).

Secondly, jQuery stores a collection of elements found in an array-like object, that's why it wouldn't work.
When you use `images[0]` you're dealing directly with DOM Objects, not jQuery, what *may* be more painful sometimes.